# Wordpress duplicates some elements and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

For example this is my template header:

```
<header>
    <?php if ( function_exists( 'jetpack_the_site_logo' ) ) jetpack_the_site_logo(); ?>

    <a class="menu-toggle">menu</div>

    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'top-nav-menu', 'container_class' => 'top-nav-menu', 'depth' => '1') ); ?>
</header>
```

Notice that `.menu-toggle` is in the header. Ok now when the template is rendered the output is like this:

[image]

So why wordpress adds that `.menu-toggle` in other 2 places? Yes I have it 3 times in the page.

- .header > .menu-toggle;
- .header > .menu-nav-menu > .menu-toggle;
- .header > .menu-nav-menu > .menu-top-nav > .menu-toggle;

What is going on? If I remove the `.menu-toggle` it removes all instances. I have no javascript that changes this code. Somehow the html from wordpress only has one `.menu-toggle`, so some js is messing up this. Even if I remove all external js and my js this still happens... Tried in incognito mode without chrome exts too.

Comment: Are you aware your code example, is using a closing `div`, and not an `a` tag? Are you using any menu walker functions in your functions.php file? I don't think it's duplicating, as you can see the other instances do not include 'menu' inside the tag. If you change this tag in the header, doe sthis also change every instance? for example, change it to `menu-toggle-2` and then refresh the page.

Comment: You were right, I missed that .. thanks! even so it's crazy that it creates it 3 times.. I would rather prefer an error than this..

Comment: Please make an answer,

Comment: What exactly was the issue?

Comment: The closing a tag as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the reason, but in your code example

```
<a class="menu-toggle">menu</div>
```

Should not be ending in `</div>` but the `</a>` tag it was started in.

Also, this sounds like there could be a `walker` that's affecting your Wordpress menu, usually found within your functions.php file.

Comment: The problem was only the closing tag. Thanks. The walker works perfectly.